# Setting Runtime Environment variable for JavaFX self-contained application in ant

Tags: java, javafx, ant, jvm, desktop-application

I am trying to build JavaFX self-contained app. Whenever I launch an app I want the third-party main class to execute first. This is a legacy code that uses Aspect-oriented programming that is why on double click on exe file I want the main class in the external jar should run first.

So for the above scenario to work, I need to set up runtime environment variables and package the .exe file.

Variables are like -Djava.system.class.loader=org.someclass.name  -javaagent:aspectj-weaver.jar

I am using ANT tool, can anyone please suggest your ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What are you using to create the self-contained application? In other words, what is Ant using behind-the-scenes?

Comment: Hi, I am using [inno setup 5.5](https://jrsoftware.org/) to package the exe. This is open-source code that I am trying to call on execution - https://github.com/ConservationInternational/Wild.ID/blob/master/Wild.ID/src/org/wildid/app/WildID.java

Build.xml file has no custom config in this project. It has Netbeans generated code.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Inno Setup, but I would assume all you have to do is customize the Ant script to pass the necessary arguments to Inno Setup.

Comment: Alright, Thank you for the suggestion. Have you used the EXE installer?